# read a full excel file chunk by chunk using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

what is quickest way to read a file chunk by chunk in pandas:
I am doing something like this which I found on stackoverflow as well . but how I will keep track of skiprow and skip footer if my file rows are for example like 1000 ?

```
# if the file contains 300 rows, this will read the middle 100
df = pd.read_excel('/path/excel.xlsx', skiprows=100, skip_footer=100)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `read_excel` does not have a chunk size argument. You can read the file first then split it manually:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name) # you have to read the whole file in total first
import numpy as np
chunksize = df.shape[0] // 1000 # set the number to whatever you want
for chunk in np.split(df, chunksize):
    # process the data
```

Unfortunately for Excel, there is no escaping reading the whole file in memory so you will have to do it this way.

If you want to do this with `skiprows` and `skipfooter`, you need to know the size of the df (you can read it first).

```
df = pd.read_excel('/path/excel.xlsx')
df_size = df.shape[0]
columns = df.columns.values
chunksize = 1000
for i in range(0, df_size - chunksize, chunksiz):
    df_chunk = pd.read_excel('/path/excel.xlsx', skiprows=i, skip_footer= (df_size - chunksize*(i+1)), names=columns)
```

Comment: what is this  df.shape[0]   doing ?

Comment: and what is  np ?

Comment: @FawadRana it will get the number of rows. `np` you will have to import numpy: `import numpy as np`

Comment: raise ValueError("skipfooter cannot be negative")
 getting this

Comment: @Fawad yeah I think the range should be then: `range(0, df_size - chunksize, chunksiz)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `range`. Assuming you want to process chunks of 100 lines in in 1000 lines excel file:

```
total = 1000
chunksize = 100
for skip in range(0, total, chunksize):
    df = pd.read_excel('/path/excel.xlsx', skiprows=skip, nrows=chunksize)
    # process df
    ...
```

Comment: will this work fine if file only have like 5 records etc ?

Comment: @FawadRana: I am sure for the range part: it will stop as soon as `skip + chunksize` would be greater of equal to `total`. I am less used to `read_excel` but I would assume that `nrows` acts as a max: if more rows are present, read only that amount, but if less are present, just read what is available. I cannot test it now anyway, but maybe you can...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `read_excel` doesn't have a `chunksize` is a little painful. There are two ways to solve this. The one that I would recommend is that you use Excel to convert the file to a CSV or TSV (tab-separated values) file. I actually like TSV much better because there is often commas in normal text, but rarely tabs.

You can automate doing this using Excel like so:

```py
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\path\to\your_file.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

worksheet.SaveAs(r'C:\path\to\output.tsv', 20)  # 20 is the code for TSV format

workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Once you have a TSV file, you can open it using `read_table()`. You don't even need `chunksize` then because `read_table()` returns an iterator, so you can `yield` from it if you want.

If you really want to keep everything in Excel, someone else has figured out how to do this, though I think it would be slower and should only be used if memory is an issue. Here is the link: https://www.giacomodebidda.com/posts/reading-large-excel-files-with-pandas/

I've included their code here for reference in case that link goes away:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd


HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATA_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(HERE, '..', 'data'))


def make_df_from_excel(file_name, nrows):
    """Read from an Excel file in chunks and make a single DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file_name : str
    nrows : int
        Number of rows to read at a time. These Excel files are too big,
        so we can't read all rows in one go.
    """
    file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, file_name))
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)

    # In this case, there was only a single Worksheet in the Workbook.
    sheetname = xl.sheet_names[0]

    # Read the header outside of the loop, so all chunk reads are
    # consistent across all loop iterations.
    df_header = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname=sheetname, nrows=1)
    print(f"Excel file: {file_name} (worksheet: {sheetname})")

    chunks = []
    i_chunk = 0
    # The first row is the header. We have already read it, so we skip it.
    skiprows = 1
    while True:
        df_chunk = pd.read_excel(
            file_path, sheetname=sheetname,
            nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows, header=None)
        skiprows += nrows
        # When there is no data, we know we can break out of the loop.
        if not df_chunk.shape[0]:
            break
        else:
            print(f"  - chunk {i_chunk} ({df_chunk.shape[0]} rows)")
            chunks.append(df_chunk)
        i_chunk += 1

    df_chunks = pd.concat(chunks)
    # Rename the columns to concatenate the chunks with the header.
    columns = {i: col for i, col in enumerate(df_header.columns.tolist())}
    df_chunks.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)
    df = pd.concat([df_header, df_chunks])
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = make_df_from_excel('claims-2002-2006_0.xls', nrows=10000)
```